# I've overwritten my Mac OS with Windows Vista, how can I get my Mac OS back?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-install Mac OS X: “Mac OS X cannot be installed on this computer.”](https://superuser.com/questions/155423/re-install-mac-os-x-mac-os-x-cannot-be-installed-on-this-computer)

I Was downloading a Windows Vista OS on my Mac and I accidentally deleted the Mac OS.
How can I get my Mac OS back? Can I use the CD's accompanied with my MAC?

Comment: I would think so, yes (If by downloading you mean installing). But probably all your data will be lost. Maybe you should first look for hfs rescue tools, if there was data on that drive, and if a rescue is possible after the drive was formatted to ntfs?

Comment: what mean hfs ????

Comment: Oh boy... HFS is the name of the file system that OS X uses... But you're going to ask me what a file system is aren't you? If you didn't have any important files then you should be able to just put in your original CD (although it's a DVD) and re-install OS X (your MAC program)

Comment: when I put the DVD to Install the MAC system...It doesnt give an option for ordinary installtion but it gives me an option for remote installtion (which it needs an network or internet connection or something like that...) what should i do ???

Comment: Take your computer to the nearest apple store.  This is most likely beyond your abilities at this point.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install OSX from the DVDs that came with your mac or get a new retail copy.

This will install the plain system - any of your work/changes will have to be restored from your backups.

Comment: with my mac there are dvd ??is there mac system on this dvd

Comment: Yes - that is what I have said